# Solution for IVP $x'(t)=\alpha x(t) + \beta- \sum_{i=1}^{m} x(t) \delta_{T_{i}}(t)$ with $x(t_0)=x_0.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

I am studying some fuzzy applications and i end needing to solve this IVP, but i dont remember much about differential equations, it seems to be a hard problem and with what i remember i couldn't solve this, i tried studying again from book but i had no clue. Can you please help me with this one.
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{array}{lcc}
x'(t)=\alpha x(t) + \beta- \sum_{i=1}^{m} x(t) \delta_{T_{i}}(t), \\
x(t_0)=x_0.
\end{array}%
\right.
\end{equation}
$\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants, $\delta$ is Dirac delta, and $T_i$ are certain times.

Answer (score 1):

One approach might be as follows: Let $\mu(t)$ denote the unit step function. Then the dynamics are equivalent to
\begin{equation*}
\dot{x}(t) = \alpha x(t) + \beta\mu(t-t_0) - \sum_{i=1}^m x(t)\delta(t-T_i).
\end{equation*}
Define $t' = t-t_0$. Then
\begin{equation*}
\dot{x}(t'+t_0) = x(t'+t_0) + \beta\mu(t') - \sum_{i=1}^m x(t'+t_0)\delta(t' - (T_i-t_0)).
\end{equation*}
Define $y(t') = x(t'+t_0)$ so that $y(0) = x(t_0) = x_0$. Also, define $T_i'=T_i-t_0$. Then we obtain the ODE starting at $t'=0$ given by
\begin{equation*}
\dot{y}(t') = y(t') + \beta\mu(t') - \sum_{i=1}^m y(t') \delta(t'-T_i'), ~ y(0) = x_0.
\end{equation*}
Now, assuming $T_i'\ge 0$ for all $i$ and applying Laplace transforms and the sifting property yields
\begin{align*}
sY(s) - y(0) ={}& Y(s) + \frac{\beta}{s} - \sum_{i=1}^m \int_{t=0}^\infty y(t)\delta(t-T_i')e^{-st}dt \\
={}& Y(s) + \frac{\beta}{s} - \sum_{i=1}^m\int_{t=-\infty}^\infty y(t)e^{-st}\delta(t-T_i')dt \\
={}& Y(s) + \frac{\beta}{s} - \sum_{i=1}^my(T_i')e^{-sT_i'},
\end{align*}
so
\begin{equation*}
Y(s) = \frac{x_0}{s-1} + \frac{\beta}{s(s-1)} - \sum_{i=1}^m y(T_i')\frac{e^{-sT_i'}}{s-1}.
\end{equation*}
Taking inverse Laplace transforms gives
\begin{equation*}
y(t') = x_0 e^{t'}\mu(t') + \beta(e^{t'}-1)\mu(t') - \sum_{i=1}^my(T_i') e^{t'-T_i'}\mu(t'-T_i') ~ \text{for $t'\ge 0$}.
\end{equation*}
The issue I find is that the trajectory $y$, as written, depends on the values $y(T_i)$, which I'm not sure how to fix. I hope this at least gives you a start!

Comment: You "fix" it dynamically: the $i=1$ term for example only applies for $t' \geq T'_1$, so $y(T'_1)=x_0 e^{T'_1} + \beta(e^{T'_1}-1)$, you use that up to $T'_2$, and so on. The result when written explicitly (i.e. in terms of what $y(T'_i)$ actually are) is a piecewise description of $y(t')$.

Comment: I see, thanks for the insight!